# Cron Expression for running a job at different intervals at different hours

Tags: linux, cron, quartz-scheduler, cron-task, cronexpression

I want to schedule a job to run every 5 mins during morning (4-8)AM and evening (7-11)PM and rest of the day every 30 minutes, how can i write a cron expression for it?

I can do this by using two cron expressions for scheduling, but can i do the task using one expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I believe you'll need 2 separate CRON expressions.

Comment: Please remember to vote if this answers your question.

Comment: i was just wondering if i could use only one expression for scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

The timings (or intensity) are different, so you need different expressions.

So something like the following is needed:

```
*/5 4-7,19-22 * * * your/command
*/30 0-3,8-18,23 * * * your/command
```